# Groupby values within a pandas dataframe array column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing a few columns with arrays. Here's a sample of one of the columns:

```
   key            arraylist
0  PROJECT-13051  [value1, value2, value4]
1  PROJECT-13050  [value2, value3, value4]
2  PROJECT-13049  [value1, value2, value3]
3  PROJECT-13048  [value3, value4, value5]
4  PROJECT-13047  [value1, value2, value5]
```

I pull this data from a sql database as comma seperated, then use the following to set as a list:

```
df[arraylist] = df[arraylist].apply(literal_eval)
```

I'd like group by the *arraylist* column and get the size of each value within the array:

```
df.groupby('arraylist').size()
```

This is resulting in the error **TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**

I'd like to get an output like so:

```
arraylist
value1      3
value2      4
value3      3
value4      3
value5      2
dtype: int64
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode) + [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas-series-value-counts):

```
df['arraylist'].explode().value_counts()
```

```
value2    4
value1    3
value4    3
value3    3
value5    2
Name: arraylist, dtype: int64
```

Optional [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html#pandas-series-sort-index) for sorted as in OP:

```
df['arraylist'].explode().value_counts().sort_index()
```

```
value1    3
value2    4
value3    3
value4    3
value5    2
Name: arraylist, dtype: int64
```

Or with [`natsorted`](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) for correct natural alphanumeric sorting:

```
from natsort import natsorted

df['arraylist'].explode().value_counts().loc[lambda s: natsorted(s.index)]
```

```
value1    3
value2    4
value3    3
value4    3
value5    2
Name: arraylist, dtype: int64
```

---

DataFrame and Imports Used:

```
from ast import literal_eval

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': ['PROJECT-13051', 'PROJECT-13050', 'PROJECT-13049',
            'PROJECT-13048', 'PROJECT-13047'],
    'arraylist': ['["value1", "value2", "value4"]',
                  '["value2", "value3", "value4"]',
                  '["value1", "value2", "value3"]',
                  '["value3", "value14", "value5"]',
                  '["value1", "value2", "value5"]']
})
df['arraylist'] = df['arraylist'].apply(literal_eval)
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, looks like the explode function was what I was after!